# Connecting Azure Data Studio to Microsoft SQL Express fails with connection error: Invalid argument

Tags: docker, ms-sql

I am running Microsoft SQL Express in a docker container on a Linux VM on my mac.
In order to make the VM available from my mac, there is some port forwarding necessary, since Virtualbox uses NAT on the default network adapter of the VM. I mapped 127.0.0.1:1433 to :1433
On the linux VM, I started the container like so:

```bsh
docker run  -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=123qwe" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I am trying to run Azure Data Studio on the same mac and connect to the container.
Connecting fails with the following error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (22): Invalid argument
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName) in /xplat/cfxfork/corefx/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs:line 5157
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.Receive(SNIPacket& packet, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.ReadSyncOverAsync(Int32 timeoutRemaining, UInt32& error)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<TryGetConnection>b__1(Task`1 _)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<<OpenAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ManagedBatchParser\ReliableConnection\ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line 314
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\Connection\ConnectionService.cs:line 524
```

Whats Wrong?

## My Set-up

- Virtualbox 6.0.18
- macos Catalina
- Microsoft SQL Express 2019
- docker CE 19.03.7

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by providing a password that has at least 9 characters:

```
docker run  -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=123qwe123" -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```